# C#: Insert strings to another string - performance issue

Tags: c#, string, performance, stringbuilder

I have a string, which is long, and a sorted dictionary of indexes and values. I should go over the elements in the dictionary and insert the value to the specified index in the string. I wrote the following code, which works fine, but very slow:

```
private string restoreText(string text){
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
  foreach(KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in _tags){
    sb.Insert(pair.Key, pair.Value);
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

The dictionary might be very big and contain 500,000 elements. 
I think that what makes this function slow is the Insert() method. For dictionary of 100,000 elements, it took almost 5 seconds.

Is there a more efficient way to write this method?

Thanks,

Maya

Comment: If it's adding `_tags` to a dictionnary, what's in `text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I don't get if you have your indices setup so that the insert won't change the others but as your code says "yes" I'll assume so too.

Can you test this one:

```
private string RestoreText(string text)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var totalLen = 0;
    var orgIndex = 0;
    foreach (var pair in _tags.OrderBy(t => t.Key))
    {
        var toAdd = text.Substring(orgIndex, pair.Key - totalLen);
        sb.Append(toAdd);
        orgIndex += toAdd.Length;
        totalLen += toAdd.Length;

        sb.Append(pair.Value);
        totalLen += pair.Value.Length;
    }
    if (orgIndex < text.Length) sb.Append(text.Substring(orgIndex));
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

it only uses append while beeing the same as your original code

Answer (score 2):

Better way would be to sort items for insertion and then append them one after another.

Since you didn't comment on the overlap, maybe you have your items sorted in the first place?

Comment: This might be quicker, but I don't think there is any guarantee. A simple profiling would find out for sure either way.

Comment: It surely will be quicker, since StringBuilder is designed for appending, and each insert has to move block of memory further down.

Answer (score 2):

Your original code will give different results depending on the order that items are returned from _tags; I very much suspect this isn't your intent.

Instead, sort the tags into order and then add them into the string builder in correct sequence:

```
private string restoreText(string text)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach( KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in _tags.OrderBy(t => t.Key))
    {
        sb.Append(pair.Value);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

If you really want to make this go as fast as possible, initialise the capacity of the `StringBuilder` up front:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(_tags.Sum(k => k.Value.Length));
```

**Update**

I missed the `text` parameter originally used to initialise the `StringBuilder`.

In order to avoid shuffling text around in memory (as caused by `StringBuilder.Insert()`), we want to stick with using `StringBuilder.Append()`.

We can do this by converting the original text into another sequence of `KeyValuePair` instances, merging those with the original list and processing in order.

It would look something like this (**note**: adhoc code):

```
private string restoreText(string text)
{
    var textPairs 
        = text.Select( (c,i) => new KeyValuePair<int,string>(i, (string)c));
    var fullSequence
        = textPairs.Union(_tags).OrderBy(t => t.Key);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach( KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in fullSequence)
    {
        sb.Append(pair.Value);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Note - I've made a whole heap of assumptions about your context, so this may not work quite right for you. Particularly be aware, that `.Union()` will discard duplicates, though there are easy workarounds for that.

Comment: but where is here (text) parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

I donnt know how about your data.

but in my test , it run fast(564ms) .

```
        Dictionary<int, string> _tags = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            _tags.Add(i, i.ToString().Length + "");
        }

        string text = new String('a' , 50000000);
        Console.WriteLine("****************************************");

        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in _tags)
        {
            sb.Insert(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("sw:" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

if you can use **append**() instead of **insert**() , it only takes 35ms...

Comment: Consider that in his example StringBuilder created with already some string. That string can be very long. "new StringBuilder(text)".

Comment: Oh,Yes 。 If the length is bigger than StringBuilder's Capacity  it will be slowly. but you can reset the capacity by yourself :)

Comment: I mean, in case of big string, Insert can be affected by this from performance point of view.

Comment: I donn't know how large is his text . but i tested the string text = new String('a' , 100000000);  , but the result is the same.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies.
The dictionary is sorted by key. The values do not overlap each other. The thing is that I should insert the values at the specified index (the key) in the parameter text, and not just concat them. This why in my code the StringBuilder is initialized with the parameter "text".
Any further help would be very appreciated.
Thanks,
Maya

Comment: I think if you use the sb.insert(pair.Key, str1) , in the next loop u must let (nextindex = pair.Key + str1.length) ?